# How to create Word office with name from createDocument(base64File) API or any another methods/API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am doing below for word document :-

Step 1. Open document from base64 . Please check below link . Document is open with random name like Document1, Document 2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.application?view=word-js-preview#word-word-application-createdocument-member(1)

```
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
        var newDoc = context.application.createDocument(base64);
        context.load(newDoc);
        //Want to give document name like newDoc.name ="sample documents"
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            newDoc.open();
        });

      });
```

Step-2 We are passing base 64 from our Rest API so want to open document with **new name** and also pass some **custom data** to new documents .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OfficeJS` doesn't provide anything for that out of the box.

Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when the dev team go through the planning process. Use the github label: `Type: product feature request` at https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions .

Comment: That's means createdocument(base64file) API useful only dress up Microsoft's documents . From Microsoft team no-one suggest what will be actual flow of this API when it was design .